# Disable new Site Health screen safely?

Tags: admin-menu

With WP 5.2 now shipping with the "Site Health" page, I'd like to be able to disable this feature -- it shows way too much about the server info.

To remove it from the menu I'm using:

```
function escode_remove_site_health_feature() {

    remove_submenu_page( 'tools.php', 'site-health.php' );
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'escode_remove_site_health_feature' );
```

This works well for removing the page from the admin menu. Now I'd like to disable access to the actual page.

My initial go-to was to check if ('site-health' === $screen->id), and then redirect that to the homepage. It feels a bit hacky though -- is there a more professional approach?

Comment: You could use the `.htaccess` file to deny access to that URL, or to redirect it to the homepage, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but defining `WP_DISABLE_FATAL_ERROR_HANDLER` to `true` will disable the site health check entirely according to [a post about site health check features in 5.1](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2019/01/14/php-site-health-mechanisms-in-5-1/).